# user id not found even when user exists

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

I have been trying to retrieve the data from instagram using instagramy but i get on getting the errors like profile doesnt exist but actually the profile username is copied from instagram itself.

```
from instagramy.plugins.analysis import analyze_users_popularity
import pandas as pd 

session_id = "58094758320%3AcPGOQQFP3YK2sq%3A0%3AAYeC7jQGmpaEYf2il0Evg60SXDeJarTsjUjc5TG7RQ"
# Instagram user_id of ipl teams
teams = ["chennaiipl", "mumbaiindians",
        "royalchallengersbangalore", "kkriders",
        "delhicapitals", "sunrisershyd",
        "kxipofficial"]
 
data = analyze_users_popularity(teams ,session_id)

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

and i keep on getting this error -------

```
HTTPError: The HTTP server returned a redirect error that would lead to an infinite loop.
The last 30x error message was:
Found


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\instagram scrapper.py", line 17, in <module>
    data = analyze_users_popularity(teams ,session_id)

  File "C:\Users\siddh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagramy\plugins\analysis.py", line 16, in analyze_users_popularity
    user = InstagramUser(username, sessionid)

  File "C:\Users\siddh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagramy\InstagramUser.py", line 61, in __init__
    data = self.get_json()

  File "C:\Users\siddh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\instagramy\InstagramUser.py", line 83, in get_json
    raise UsernameNotFound(self.url.split("/")[-2])

UsernameNotFound: InstagramUser('chennaiipl') not Found
```